# Shopware 6 on local system installation error

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6, shopware5

Actually I just wanted to install shopware 6 on my local system Xampp, but unfortunately I'm not able to install because it's giving an error please find error file ,[image: installation error]   . my system requirements are all showing good but i don't understand why it showing this error. i ma installing in window 10 on Xampp server.

please please could some one help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shopware 6 does not support windows installations, but you should be able to install it under [WSL2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).

Please refer to the [installation guide](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/installation/overview#system-requirements).

Comment: thanks for your response now i have installed wsl2 but how can I enter inside shopware folder? also i have cloned files using `$ git clone https://github.com/shopware/development.git`  but where I can see cloned files, please help